# How to filter children by parent field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Example, models.py:

```py
class Guy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Mom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=MOTHER_NAMES, default=MOTHER_NAMES[0][0])
    guy = models.OneToOneField(Guy, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

How to get queryset of Guys whose Mom's name is 'Sophia'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the *validation_contract_id*s of mothers whose name is *Sophia* and you can find the children whose id in this validation_contract_ids.

You can use following query:

```
Guy.objects.filter(id__in=Mom.objects.filter(name='Sophia').values_list('guy_id',flat=True))
```

Comment: what I should do if model Mom has 2 relationships (guy1 - OneToOneField to Guy model and guy2 - OneToOneField to Guy model), how get queryset of guy1 + guy2 and Mom's name still 'Sophia'

Comment: If you mean a mother related two guy, it is impossible because your Mom model OneToOne related with guy.Otherwise, you have two mother and this query return these two mother.As a suggestion, you can add foreignkey your guy model and connect it with mother. Because you have OneToMany relationship between mother and guy

Comment: In the current state of the project, this is a very costly change. Otherwise, I can make 2 similar querysets (one for guy1 and one for guy2), and then combine them.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have multiple guy whose their mother has name Sophia. If it is true, you don't need multiple query.This query returns these  guys

Comment: I mean two fields in model Mom (guy1, guy2, OneToOneField to Guy), not two objects (in my example, having two different fields for one model is not right, but the situation is different in the project and there it is justified)